# Como ultrapassar XMLHttpRequest cannot load?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

Aparece me este erro. Como o ultrapassar?

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load "url exemplo". No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Código

```
var url = "http://www. url exemplo"; //url que tem a informação
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        console.log(json);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Esse código está executando dentro de um `iframe` com o parâmetro `sandbox`, certo? E em qual *browser* essa mensagem apareceu?

Comment: Eu estou a usar o chrome. Não percebo o porque de através de este url "http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json" conseguir ir buscar o conteúdo e no url que estou a utilizar já não o conseguir.

Comment: Talvez essa url dê suporte a CORS. Não percebi nada abrindo ela no Chrome e visualizando os *headers*, mas talvez tentando fazer uma chamada ajax pra ela... Vou fazer um teste.

Comment: Isso mesmo! Veja [esse teste](http://jsfiddle.net/cswdqs18/1/), abra o console, verá que o primeiro tem sucesso e o segundo falha - acusando justamente a falta do `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. A primeira URL dá suporte a CORS, a segunda não.

Comment: Obrigada. Então para que o url dê suporte a CORS, (visto que só tenho acesso ao url, não tenho acesso a mais nada) existe algo que eu possa fazer?

Comment: Infelizmente, não, se o servidor não é seu não é você quem decide se ele aceita ou não ajax de domínios diferentes. Sua única opção é usar um *proxy* (ex.: você faz a chamada para seu próprio servidor, que por sua vez faz um `curl` ou similar ao site que você quer consultar, e retorna a resposta de volta pro *browser*).

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, nota-se que o *browser* estabeleceu a origem da chamada como `null`. A origem (o trio esquema/domínio/porta que identifica *onde* você está) normalmente refere-se ao site em que o código está executando - seja o próprio site (se o código for seu) ou não (se for um código de terceiros - um anúncio por exemplo - executando no seu site). Mas se ela é nula, isso é um sinal de que o código está num ambiente "protegido" (*sandboxed*). Muito provavelmente, um `iframe` com o atributo `sandboxed` e **sem** a opção `allow-same-origin`.

A um código nessas circunstâncias não é considerado **confiável** pelo seu *host*, e portanto não pode acessar recursos da mesma origem (i.e. pela [Política da Mesma Origem](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_de_mesma_origem), é como se esse código estivesse em outro site, não no seu) [*inclusive* fazer chamadas ajax pra mesma origem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14619562/520779). Creio que alguns *browsers* sequer permitiriam chamadas ajax para qualquer lugar (alguns testes que fiz no passado - ver link acima - tiveram esse resultado).

Entretanto, me parece que o *browser* que você está usando é mais "razoável" - ele permite que conteúdo *sandboxed* faça ajax para servidores que implementam [*Cross-Origin Resource Sharing*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (CORS). Dessa forma, ele verificou se o servidor em questão (o seu próprio? algum outro?) retornava o *header* `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, de modo a descobrir se era ou não permitido outros sites fazerem requisições ajax para ele. Na ausência de uma resposta positiva (i.e. a ausência do *header*), ele tomou a opção segura que era de bloquear a chamada.

Para resolver, você teria que das três uma:

- Retirar o atributo `sandboxed` do seu `iframe`;
- acrescentar a opção `allow-same-origin` no mesmo; ou:
- Habilitar CORS no seu servidor.

Cada uma delas tem implicações na segurança. É preciso primeiro responder a si própria "de onde vem esse código?", "ele é confiável?" e "que mal teria se um site X qualquer fizesse requisições ajax pro meu servidor?", antes de decidir por uma solução adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Olá. você pode fazer assim:
Exemplo:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET","https://api.github.com/users/itasouza");
xhr.send(null);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
        console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    }
}
```